# Java: How I can improve this cod e?

Tags: java

I made this, basically the user can toggle options to be able to see them or not in the application, i wanted to know how i can improve this class. there are parts like SEARCH & MAP that only change the value in the map and nothing else, would be better to create an abstract class and extend for each type? TypeWithoutToggle (this will only change the value in the map for the type and implement empty #toggle)) TypeWithToggle.. then extend these depending.

```
public enum ToggleType {
    NAME {
        @Override
        public void toggle(VideoPlayer videoPlayer) {
            videoPlayer.doToggleName();
        }
    },
    EDITOR {
          @Override
          public void toggle(VideoPlayer videoPlayer) {
              if (videoPlayer.isTrue("EDITOR"))
                 videoPlayer.createEditors();
              else 
                 videoPlayer.deleteEditors();
        }
    },
    SEARCH {
        @Override
        public void toggle(VideoPlayer videoPlayer) {
            
        }
    },
    MAP {
        @Override
        public void toggle(VideoPlayer videoPlayer) {
            // handle on {@link VideoPlayer#create()}
        }
    },

    protected abstract void toggle(VideoPlayer videoPlayer); 

    public void run(VideoPlayer videoPlayer) {
        videoPlayer.toggleMap.put(name(), !videoPlayer.isTrue(name()));
        toggle(videoPlayer);
    }
```

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is mostly opinion based, but there are at least two things that I could mention:

First is you are coupling `VideoPlayer` with `ToggleType`. There should be a separate method, probably in `VideoPlayer` (or a `VideoPlayerToggler`), that is responsible for the toggle that accepts `ToggleType`.

Example:

```
switch(toggleType):
  case NAME:
    doToggleName()
    break;
  case EDITOR:
      if (videoPlayer.isTrue("EDITOR"))
           videoPlayer.createEditors();
      else 
           videoPlayer.deleteEditors();
    break;
   ...
```

Let's assume that you will add a new component that can be toggled, like a `MenuComponent`.  So it might scale better, and decouples your code. With your approach, you would have to add another abstract method, that will handle your type. In short- **ToggleType doesn't have to know what or how to toggle.** There might be many toggle handlers depending on your environment, configuration or other factors.

Secondly if you put this method inside `VideoPlayer`, then you don't have to expose any methods, keep everything well encapsulated and private, which is a good idea in general.

Answer (score 1):

You should not expose the toggleMap attribute on VideoPlayer class. Instead the should be encapsulated as a method in VideoPlayer class.
It's difficult to give a more detailed comment only by looking at these few lines.